# Custom Chart point DataLabel Position

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set a DataLabel of a chart point in VBA, and cant find the way to do it.
In the last part of this code I set up the properties of the chart's point, but I don't know how to set up a custom position, I attach a picture of the result I'm trying to have:

```
objCht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ResBook.Sheets(Right(NombreHoja, 2)).Range("P1:R" & UltFilaGrafico)
objCht.Activate
Call AgregarEjeSecundario("Velocidad [km/h]", 3)

ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = CInt(TargetVelocity) + 10
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = 0
ActiveChart.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom


'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(50).MarkerStyle = xlDiamond
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    '.Points(StopEventRow).MarkerStyle = xlDiamond
    .Points(StopEventRow).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleTriangle
    '.Points(StopEventRow).MarkerSize = 10
    .Points(StopEventRow).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)    'Rojo
    .Points(StopEventRow).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(1, 1, 1)

    .Points(StopEventRow).HasDataLabel = True
    .Points(StopEventRow).DataLabel.text = "Detención"
    '.Points(StopEventRow).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlValue
    .Points(StopEventRow).DataLabel.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    '.Points(StopEventRow).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionCustom
    '.Points(StopEventRow).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowLabel

End With
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish through the VBA code.

Here I manually set up the position of the label, I´m trying to get this done by the code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example I figured out using the macro recorder:

```
Sub AddDataLabel()

    Dim dl As DataLabel, cht As Chart, pt As Point

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

    Set pt = cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(6)

    pt.ApplyDataLabels

    Set dl = pt.DataLabel

    With dl
        .Text = "hello"
        .Font.Color = vbRed
        'move label relative to data point
        .Top = pt.Top - 15
        .Left = pt.Left + 15
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]